# Returning from type to object

Tags: c#, types

I'm having trouble getting the MarshalAs attribute in my project. As in the example below, I have to send the Type variable named "t" to different parts of the project as a Type.

But somewhere I had to access the ParameterInfo object from the variable "t". How can I do it?

```
ParameterInfo pi = SomeObject;
Type t = pi.ParameterType;                    

ParameterInfo pi2 = t.ToObject(); // ?????

var att = pi.GetCustomAttribute<MarshalAsAttribute>(); // Return object
var att2 = t.GetCustomAttribute<MarshalAsAttribute>(); // Return null
```

Comment: What are you doing that you would ever need this code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ToObject` to fetch `MarshalAs` attribute.

For a method:

```
public void Test1()
{
    var method = TestMethod;

    foreach (var parameter in method.Method.GetParameters())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(parameter);

        var attribute = parameter.GetCustomAttribute<MarshalAsAttribute>();

        if (attribute != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(attribute.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public static void TestMethod([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)] int i, int j)
{
}
```

Result:

```
Int32 i
SysInt

Int32 j
```

For a field:

```
public void Test2()
{
    var unmanagedType = typeof(MyStruct)
        .GetField(nameof(MyStruct.I))?
        .GetCustomAttribute<MarshalAsAttribute>()?
        .Value;

    Console.WriteLine(unmanagedType);
}

private struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
    public int I;
}
```

Result:

```
SysInt
```

Comment: Dear aybe, MarsalAs attribute can be obtained from Parameter object. I know this and I mentioned it in my first post.

What I would like to know if it is possible is as follows:

<pre><code>ParameterInfo pi = SomeObject;
Type t = pi.ParameterType; 

ParameterInfo pi2 = t.?????????;</code></pre>

Comment: If you want to get that type's attributes, yes. Else, pass the `ParameterInfo` to your code.